# AVPlayer url duration Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, avplayer

I am trying to get the duration of a .mp3 url using AVPlayer, iOS 13.7 and Xcode 12.0.

First, with AVAudioPlayer was working but it didn't worked with remote urls so i changed to AVPlayer so i can use the links that comes from API.

This is my get duration method:

```
private func getDuration() -> TimeInterval? {
    guard let url = url else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioAsset.duration)
    return duration
}
```

In debugging, the url is the right one, downloading the .mp3 file. The `audioAsset.duration` returns the next value:

```
    CMTime
  - value : 0
  - timescale : 0
  ▿ flags : CMTimeFlags
    - rawValue : 17
  - epoch : 0
```

and `CMTimeGetSeconds(audioAsset.duration)` give NaN.

Is there any way to get the remote url duration using just AVPlayer?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are not giving the `AVURLAsset` object to `AVPlayer`.

Comment: This duration is inside a model which is given to AVPlayer. The player plays the url, but the duration is always nan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

After a lot of debugging and links tried, the actual problem is that AVURLAsset works with links that can play directly into the browser.

For example, for a link like this: `https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3` you will get the duration, but for a downloadable .mp3 or .m4a that does not have the extension at the end it won't get the duration. Guess it's about how metadata is saved on both on them.